# Display 3 tables always in the middle of the page

Tags: html, css

I have been using CSS to have an image always in the middle of the page, but now I want 6 links to the left of the image and 6 links to the right of the image.  I want all three to stay in the middle of the page as the page changes in size.

I'm not sure if I need 3 tables, or 1 table with only one row in the center? I think 1 table would be easier, but can I have 6 rows in the first column, 1 row in the second column (the image would take up most of the row) and 6 rows in the third column? Once I have the table(s) setup, then I need them to float in the middle of the page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here's the code I use to center the image.

```
IMG.centered {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: we need a little more html and css you tried to help you, else it looks like your asking to do the job for you :)

Comment: try: `position: absolute;` instead of `fixed`.

Comment: Need more than This. post your HTML

Answer (score 2):

if display:flex is fine, you need no tables:

```css
html {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
}
body {
  margin:auto;
  border:solid;
}
nav {
  counter-reset:links;
  display:flex;
  background:gray;
  padding:0 1em;
}
img {
  margin:1em;
}
ul {
  padding:0;
  margin:auto;
  list-style-type:none;
}
a:after {
  counter-increment:links;
  content:' 'counter(links);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">link</a></li>
  </ul>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/200/nature/7"/>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">link</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**it is only a guess since you provided no HTML and too little CSS**

Comment: click full page to run the snippet on entire page

Comment: GCyrillus, that is awesome and is exactly what I needed!